# How to find closest bigger time from an array to DateTime.Now

Tags: c#, linq, parsing, datetime

I am trying to find closest bigger time to current time.
This is the code that i have:

```
var busTimes = new string[]
    {
        "15:00",
        "16:00",
        "17:00",
        "18:00",
        "19:00",
        "20:00",
        "21:00"
        }
        .Select(x => DateTime.Parse(x))
        .ToList();

var now = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;

var closestTime = (from x in busTimes
                   where x.busTimes.TimeOfDay > now
                   orderby x.busTimes.TimeOfDay ascending
                   select x).First();
```

But I get this error:

> Error CS1061  'DateTime' does not contain a definition for 'busTimes' and 
>       no extension method 'busTimes' accepting a first argument of type 'DateTime' 
>       could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How can i fix this?

Comment: I'd get rid of the `.ToList();` call. it's completely unnecessary here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x` is a `DateTime`, like the error message said, there is no `busTimes` property on it.

```
var closestTime = (from x in busTimes
    where x.TimeOfDay > now
    orderby x.TimeOfDay ascending
    select x).First();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be:

```
var closestTime = (from x in busTimes
        where x.TimeOfDay > now
        orderby x.TimeOfDay ascending
        select x).First();
```

As the `x` identifier represents a `DateTime` and a `DateTime` struct doesn't have a 'busTimes' property.